# How to open external application and run specific function of that application in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new mac developer and I want to do the following things:

1. I created a simple application, and I want to click a button in my application to open up external application located on mac (like open Disk Utility) (I know how to do this part by using launchApplication)
2. Besides open the application, I also want to execute specific functions (like erase function in Disk Utility) automatically after open the disk utility application. (I have no idea how to do this) Could you possible show me some demos I am really new in mac ?

Thanks !!

Comment: You should take a look at Applescript. Also for an app being able to control another app sounds a bit dangerous to me, just make sure you're not violating too much of the user's right.

Comment: With the new sandboxing rules you may run into problems with apple script and any other form of "make application X do something".

Answer (score 0):

The external application should be a Scriptable application.

> A **scriptable application** is one that makes its operations and data available in response to AppleScript messages, called Apple events. An Apple event is a kind of interprocess message that can specify complex operations and data. Apple events make it possible to encapsulate a high-level task in a single package that can be passed across process boundaries, performed, and responded to with a reply event.

You can find more details in the related Apple documentation: [Cocoa Scripting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001982-BCICHGIE)

Comment: Can I use command line to execute the same function? I think if that works, we can use NSTask or other class to execute right?

Comment: You can use [NSAppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to control scriptable application from whithin your app.

Comment: Thanks, if possible could you provide me a tutorial, I am really new in mac dev? Thanks again !!